# Include external package in angular components library

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to use an external library in my angular components library project.

So, after importing the module in a component module i'll use it in the component:

```
import { CalendarModule } from '@syncfusion/ej2-angular-calendars';
....
@NgModule({
declarations: [ MyInputComponent ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule, CalendarModule
  ],
  exports: [ MyInputComponent ]
})
export class MyInputModule {}
```

It builds perfectly but when i include the library in a project i got this error:

```
ERROR in ../my-components/dist/my-components/fesm5/my-components.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@syncfusion/ej2-angular-calendars' in '/Users/.../Dev/ui-components/dist/ui-components/fesm5'
```

I can't understand what i am doing wrong...

Thanks

Comment: what version of angular are you using? 
Do you use angular/cli?

Comment: Did you install it using "npm install @syncfusion/ej2-angular-calendars" ? The error says that module not found int he node_modules folder of  your project.

Comment: I installed it in my library... i'm using angular 7 and cli only in the lib

Comment: I had a similar problem with _moment.js_ 
Did you add it to `ng-package.json`'s `umdModuleIds` array?

I additionally hat to tweak my imports to
`import * as momentNs from 'moment';
export const moment = momentNs;`

Maybe that helps

Comment: @Arikael so you added "lib": {
    "umdModuleIds": {
      "moment": "momentNS", 
?

Comment: no, "moment": "moment",
see https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/docs/dependencies.md


But I think the real culprit was the import in my case.

`momentNs` is just the the temporary imported `momentjs` namespace

Comment: Nope... i tryed but with no luck